# How do I progress Farkas' companion story line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I’ve beaten both the “Hired Muscle” and “Trouble in Skyrim” quests, and every time I ask someone in the circle about a job, they just say “aren’t you already running a job for Farkas?”

I’m not. I want to marry Farkas, but I can’t get any further with the companion story line. How do I progress Farkas' companion story line?

Comment: Just to confirm, you have spoken to Skjor?

Comment: i’m passed that. skjor is dead

Comment: The part your asking us about explicitly requires talking to Skjor. So either your further ahead than your telling us you are, or you've killed a major NPC and can not physically move any further in the storyline

Comment: Are you at least able to confirm what the *last* quest you completed in the questline was? As it is, this is way to vague

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete the Entire Companion questline to get him as a Marriage option, these include:

- Take Up Arms
- Proving Honor
- The Silver Hand
- Blood's Honor
- Purity of Revenge
- Glory of the Dead

If the quest is bugged it can have a plethora of reasons(mainly due to the repeatable quests).

Options are:

- Sleep for a day or 2, it might fix itself
- save, attack the companions and then either sheave your weapon or
  reload and it might reset.
- Some quests are wrongfully categorizes, some other miscellaneous
  quests might block it and need to be completed first
- Try everybody there might be a single one that does give a job but
  think u already tried that.
- Bounties might cause the issue, try paying them al off or getting one
  and then paying it off

IF that doesn't work your last option is using console commands.

Comment: that’s the thing, it’s not letting me start any new tasls